# Alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have a seemingly simple alignment issue I can't seem to fix. I have a basic menu inside a div. I want to add content underneath the menu, so I created another div with a top-margin of 10px. For some reason, it is not recognizing the content as separate and keeps inserting the content in line with the menu. The information span class is being placed on the same level as the menu. Please let me know if you see a problem with the way these divisions are set up!

The CSS code just has a padding of 10px on the top for the information class.

HTML CODE:

```
  <body>

    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">HOME PAGE</h1>
        <img src="pic.jpg" alt="Picture" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 45px"/>
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr">EXAMPLE</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">EXAMPLE</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                        <a href="#">EXAMPLE</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                    <span class="sdt_wrap">
                        <span class="sdt_link">EXAMPLE</span>
                        <span class="sdt_descr"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="sdt_box">
                    <a href="#">A</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div> 
    <span class="information">
    <p> 
    Some content here
    </p>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle or snippet with css

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing your CSS it sounds like a float issue. You need to clear floated elements. Assuming you did them correctly they're most likely on the `li` tags. You can use `overflow:hidden` on your parent `ul`:

```
ul#sdt_menu{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or you can use a cleafix method

```
ul#sdt_menu:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

If neither of these work please post your CSS for further help